# Create swatches based on existing swatch with extendscript (javascript)

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'd like to create many color swatches in InDesign based on an existing color swatch. I would like to take the numbers of the existing swatch, and create new swatches by adding values, i.e. Cyan +1, Magenta +2, Yellow +0, Black +0. Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by adding values? It might be helpful to include some know input data and what you are expecting the output to look like.

Comment: I'll have a base color swatch, let's say it's C50 M50 Y0 K0. Using those numbers I'd like to create an additional color swatch with +1C, making a second swatch that's C51 M50 Y0 K0, and then another that's +1M, making a third swatch that's C50 M51 Y0 K0, and another that +1Y from the base swatch C50 M50 Y1 K0, and so on. The script will need to reference the base swatch, regardless of what color it is.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question with several cases? Im still having trouble understanding your request. Specifically do you add a component one at a time and create 4 variants of single swatch? or apply your components as a whole and generate one swatch?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarification, hopefully this will do it:

Comment: THE SCRIPT: Takes an existing swatch, called BASE, which the user can change prior to running the script, and creates 8 additional swatches, with the following parameters based on the BASE swatch: #1: C+1 #2: M+1 #3 Y+1 #4 K+1 #5 C-1 #6 M-1 #7 Y-1 #8 K-1.

Comment: WORKFLOW EXAMPLE 1: User opens document with the BASE swatch in it. User changes the parameters of the swatch to be: C:20 M:20 Y:20 K:10. User runs the script, and gets 8 new swatches in the swatch palette: #1 C:21 M:20 Y:20 K:10 #2 C:20 M:21 Y:20 K:10 #3 C:20 M:20 Y:21 K:10 #4: C:20 M:20 Y:20 K:11 #5: C:19 M:20 Y:20 K:10 #6 C:20 M:19 Y:20 K:10 #7: C:20 M:20 Y:19 K:10 #8: C:20 M:20 Y:20 K:9.

Comment: WORKFLOW EXAMPLE 2: User changes the parameters of the BASE swatch again to be: C:40 M:40 Y:40 K:20. User runs the script, and gets 8 additional swatches in the swatch palette: #1 C:41 M:40 Y:40 K:20 #2 C:40 M:41 Y:40 K:20 #3 C:40 M:40 Y:41 K:20 #4: C:40 M:40 Y:40 K:21 #5: C:39 M:40 Y:40 K:20 #6 C:40 M:39 Y:40 K:20 #7: C:40 M:40 Y:39 K:20 #8: C:40 M:40 Y:40 K:19. User now has a total of 16 new swatches.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job.

```
const clamp = (value, min, max) => Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));

// value: { c: number, m: number, y: number, k: number }
const swatch = (value) => {
  const results = [];
  const keys = ['c', 'm', 'y', 'k'];

  for (let i = 1; i >= -1; i -= 2) {
    for (let key of keys) {
      if (clamp(value[key] + i, 0, 100) != value[key]) {
        results.push({ ...value, [key]: value[key] + i });
      }
    }
  }
  
  return results;
};

console.log(swatch({
  c: 40,
  m: 20,
  y: 40,
  k: 20
}));
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you Han Yolo! I will try this out when I am back in front of a computer later today. Are there parts of this code that I will need to customize, or is it good as-is? (I am a scripting novice, forgive me.)

Comment: the code doesn't parse cmy expressions. It expects the  input to be in component form as you can see in swatch. It also clamps values to (0, 100). It should work as is.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the following error message upon running: Error Number: 3 Error String: Cannot assign value. Engine: main. Line: 1 Source: const clamp = (value, min, max) => Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max)); Offending Text: > This line is also being called out in the ExtendScript Debugger 1.1.0 with the error "Cannot assign value <="

Comment: you need to downcompile/translate this to es5 or whatever standard you are targeting. i suspect that ExtendScript or whatever js engine you are using does not support es6, so it cant parse fat arrow functions, let/const keywords, or spreads.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rather simple straightforward implementation:

```
var COLORS = app.activeDocument.colors;
var BASE = COLORS.itemByName("BASE");

function add_color(name,c,m,y,k) {
    var color = COLORS.add();
        color.space = ColorSpace.CMYK;
        color.colorValue = [
            BASE.colorValue[0] + c,
            BASE.colorValue[1] + m,
            BASE.colorValue[2] + y,
            BASE.colorValue[3] + k ];
        color.name = get_name(name);
}

// color names should not be the same, it adds "+" to the repeated names
function get_name(name) {
    try {
        return get_name(COLORS.itemByName(name).name + "+");
    } catch(e) {
        return name;
    }
}

add_color("#1", 1, 0, 0, 0);
add_color("#2", 0, 1, 0, 0);
add_color("#3", 0, 0, 1, 0);
add_color("#4", 0, 0, 0, 1);

add_color("#5",-1, 0, 0, 0);
add_color("#6", 0,-1, 0, 0);
add_color("#7", 0, 0,-1, 0);
add_color("#8", 0, 0, 0,-1);
```

Perhaps you need to think of better way to handle the repeated color names.